# O que é Arrow Function e quando usar?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

eu estou com uma dúvida, estou estudando o ES6 porém não entendi muito o que o Arrow Function substitui, pesquisei e vi que é a função 
`this`. Gostaria de saber melhor com um exemplo sem e com Arrow Function, e saber como fica o código.

Será que alguem poderia me ajudar nessa ?

Comment: Está utilizando `TypeScript`?

Comment: `Arrow Function` traduzindo para o português são **Funções de Flechas** 
É só um meio de se escrever funções de uma maneira mais compacta.

Comment: Exemplo em TypeScript: A função **let func = function (name:string): string {
 return `My name is: ${name}`
}**. Traduzida em Arrow Function: **let func = (name:string) => `My name is: ${name}`**