# Como funciona o "array.sort()"?

Tags: javascript, array, classificação

Como funciona o

```
array.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

?

Por que este simbolo `=>`, e porque esta operação `a - b` está subtraindo os elementos? Isso não faz sentido pra mim.

Comment: Isso `=>` se chama Arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: Não acho que a pergunta deveria ficar como pendente, o questionamento está bem claro e a explicação é simples.

Comment: Sobre a sintaxe com `=>` (Arrow functions): [O que é Arrow Function e quando usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/270616/74) // Sobre o `Array.prototype.sort`: [Como o método sort funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248356/74). Fechei como ampla demais porque são duas coisas totalmente distintas.

Comment: @bfavaretto se tivesse indicado a sup do sort antes do primeiro fechamento eu nem teria respondido, e claro também não tinha achado ampla porque fazia tudo parte de uma explicação do `sort()`, embora eu sabia que o `=>` já tinha resposta, da função em si não.

Comment: @Maniero Fechei primeiro pra buscar os links depois, pois tinha certeza de que existiam no site.

Comment: E escolhi "ampla" e não duplicata porque fiquei na dúvida se era uma boa linkar duas duplicatas sobre assuntos diferentes @Maniero.

Comment: @bfavaretto isso é oque mais tem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parte já foi respondido em [O que significa o operador "=>"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/101) (ou todas estas indicadas em [O que é Arrow Function e quando usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/270616/101)).

Faz todo sentido. Sempre que você for usar uma função deve ler a documentação dela antes de usar. Não pode usar "na loucura", tem que estudar a ferramenta, saber como ela funciona, como é o jeito de usar. Veja a [documentação da função](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Lá diz que se o valor retornado por esta função *lambda* for negativo então o elemento `a` é menor que o elemento `b`, se o resultado for 0 então são iguais, e se for maior que 0 o `b` é menor que `a`. E saber qual é o menor é uma necessidade básica para classificar uma coleção de dados. Portanto você está passando para o `sort()` uma função que indica qual dos dois elementos é o menor ou igual, assim o algoritmo de classificação saberá o que fazer, mas o critério para decidir isso você faz como quiser.